# here upload file code in error, how it solved

Tags: yii2

```
Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = Yii::$app->basePath . '/uploads/';
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');
        $model->filename = $image->name;
        $ext = end((explode(".", $image->name)));
        $model->photo = Security::generateRandomKey().".{$ext}"; 
        $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $model->photo;
        if($model->save()){
            $image->saveAs($path);
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

---

i want yo file name inserted into databse..
this code through file uploded into upload folder
 but file name not inserted into databse.
so..
what i can changes in code??

Comment: You have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form right?

Comment: yes enctype add in form

Comment: error show in this line $model->filename = $image->name;

Comment: Try `$model->filename = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');` Then `$model->filename->save($path);` Or at least do `print_r($image);` after `$image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');`

Comment: How do you usually debug your coding? I know it doesn't take much time to post a question but sometimes debugging takes much less!

Comment: i wiil try just mint.

Comment: nothing display anything... blank page..

Comment: You mean the print_r($image); doesn't display anything?

Comment: You can always.... neah.... you never accept answers anyway.

Comment: ya not display any value

Comment: Add the code from the view file where the form is coded. Eg: `<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]);  ?>` and the file field code. Add it in the question.

Comment: already added this code..

Comment: The code in question is from the controller not the view file. I need view file code.

Comment: Also you do have the use statement added at the top right? I mean for `UploadedFile`. Eg: `use yii\web\UploadedFile;`

Comment: yes this statement added

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html

Answer (score 0):

In your model make sure you have declared variable "photo"

```
class ModelName extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  public $attachment;
```

and in rules for this attribute:

```
['attachment', 'file', 'extensions' => 'jpg, png', 'mimeTypes' => 'image/jpeg, image/png'],
```

in your view file you have

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'attachment')->fileInput() ?>
```

and in your code:

```
    $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'attachment');
    $model->filename = $image->baseName;
    $ext = $image->extension;
    $model->photo = Security::generateRandomKey().".{$ext}"; 
    $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $model->photo;
```

BTW: in your code you have model field "photo" (**$model->photo = Security::generateRandomKey().".{$ext}";** ) and also you are using this name for fileinput attribute name (**$image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');**). It could be a reason for error.

Comment: i will put this code but error occur Class 'yii\helpers\Security' not found

Comment: add use yii\base\Security; at top of file

Comment: just a mint i will cheack

Comment: how to image name inser into database??

Comment: try $model->filename = $image->name;